# eigenfunctions of laplacian on infinite strip

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, spectral-theory

I am trying to solve 
\begin{equation}
-\Delta{u} = \lambda \cdot u
\end{equation} with zero-boundary-conditions on the unbounded domain $\Omega = \mathbb{R} \times (0,\pi)$ for $\lambda \ge 0$ in the Sobolev spaces $H^{1}_{0}(\Omega)$. 
Since the embedding of $H^{1}_{0}(\Omega) \rightarrow L^{2}(\Omega)$ is not compact, the laplacian shouldn´t have a discrete spectrum. However, I was not able to find any eigenfunctions. 
$u_{\lambda}(x)=sin(\sqrt{(\lambda/2}) \; x) \; sin(\sqrt{(\lambda/2)} \; y)$ is obviously not in $L^{2}(\Omega)$. But how can I prove that

1) there are no other $H^{1}_{0}$-eigenfunctions?

2) the spectrum is $[0,\infty)$?

Edit: Also, any reference on either (1) or (2) would be greatly appreciated